# Colorizing the grails logger

Tags: grails, logging, colors, log4j

I am attempting to colorize my grails logger.  However, whenever I do I get the following error:

```
Error log4j:ERROR Unexpected char [h] at position 2 in conversion patterrn.
```

I read through the log4j appenders documentation and the example is pretty much verbatim from the docs, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout

Here's what my code looks like to set the console logger:

```
def log4jLayoutPatternConsole = new org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout("%highlight{%d [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n%throwable}{FATAL=magenta, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}")

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console(
                name: 'stdout',
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO,
                layout: log4jLayoutPatternConsole
                )
```

Answer (score 2):

Colour highlighting is a feature of log4j 2, Grails uses version 1.2.

Comment: Is there a way to get my grails application to use the 2 series?  This would involve me downloading the JAR and put it in the /lib folder, correct?

Comment: @ThomasFarvour you would have to exclude the default log4j plugin, and then you'd have to write your logging configuration in the normal log4j2 style with an XML or JSON configuration file - the Grails DSL won't work.  Finally you'd have to include the relevant SLF4J binding to route the Grails loggers-by-convention to log4j 2.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a simpler way to get colorized logging with 1.2?  I saw a jcabi-log plugin.  Is this usable in grails via the DSL?

Comment: @ThomasFarvour you could use a suitable log4j 1.2 compatible appender implementation such as http://blog.uncommons.org/2006/04/09/colour-coded-console-logging-with-log4j/